# what is the use of glProgramLocalParameter and glProgramEnvParameter

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-4

They are defined in the NV gpu program 4 extension here https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/gpu_program4.txt

Is this the only way to transfer constant data over to program? Has this been replaced by uniforms when we use GLSL?

I also saw glProgramBufferParameter somewhere and got more confused. Is that for Shader storage buffers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> They are defined in the NV gpu program 4 extension here

No, they're referenced by this extension. Defined they were in [ARB_vertex_program](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_program.txt)

> Is this the only way to transfer constant data over to program?

If you're using the old and dusted ARB_…_program extensions, then yes. If you use GLSL then Uniforms are the way to go.

> I also saw glProgramBufferParameter somewhere and got more

There is no function named glProgramBufferParameter. There is however a function `glProgramBufferParameters*NV`. The NV in the end is important, it tells that this is a NVidia specific extension. Again this is for use with a ARB_…*program style shader and not for GLSL; the NVidia OpenGL implementation internally compiles GLSL to ARB*…_program style shaders.

Anyway, program buffer objects have a GLSL counterpart in the form for Uniform Buffer Objects: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object